# Need some help for a first time Office Communications Server Install

Tags: windows-server-2008, installation, ms-office-communicator

I want to install Office Communications Server on Server 2008. I have never installed OCS and I am looking for a good walkthrough of the installation process.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For our installation, I used the TechNet documentation.

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb676082.aspx

Answer (score 2):

Be sure to grab all the documentation and sort through it at the link a_hardin posted. In some cases the information you need will be in one document or another. Unfortunately, though, I don't know that any of it references an installation on Windows Server 2008.

Answer (score 1):

I believe only R2 of OCS 2007 supports 2008, and it requires 64bit.

Read through the installation documentation a couple of times and you'll be fine, also you could setup a virtual environmnent to test the installation with. That's what I did the first time I setup OCS.

Answer (score 0):

So far I have made it through all the steps successfully up to starting the services which I think is because I need to get my certificates in order. The setup routine is very nicely setup and guides you through anything you need to know.